copied file to lib folder was automatically removed
I coped libssl.so.1.0.0 to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 for a game.
I'm not sure what I did (reboot/apt upgrade/etc), but somehow it was automatically deleted.
How can I copy the file there and keep it there?

Why did you install it what is it supposed to fix? What error or message do you get? Please use the edit function and add some info to the question.

I'm not aware of any Ubuntu process that would remove a manually copied library from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu except in order to replace it with one from an installed/updated package. However the appropriate place to put such libraries would likely be /usr/local/lib - see for example 4.9. /usr/local : Local hierarchy in the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. You may need to run sudo ldconfig after in order to add the library to the runtime linker cache.
